# prisma findMany not returning id's of rows

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

Using prisma `findMany` to fetch rows from postgres database, but it's not returning the actual `id` of the row, just the other columns. I need the id so that I can pass that the frontend can use it for CRUD operations, is there a way to return those ID's?

```
const bookList = await prisma.books.findMany({
        where: {
          author_id: "123",
        }
      });
```

schema

```
model books {
  id              String               @id @default(uuid())
  name            String               @db.VarChar(50)
  author_id       String
}
```

Expected response

```
[{
   "id": "some-uid",
   "name": "some-book-name"
}]
```

^ it includes the `id` field, which I'm currently not getting

Comment: Can you share your schema file and sample response which you expect?

Comment: @NurulSundarani updated schema, by id i just mean the default id of the row

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour is to return all the fields in `findMany` but you can explicitly select fields that should be returned by [select](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields#select-specific-fields) clause.

Here is an example:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// A `main` function so that you can use async/await
async function main() {
  // ... you will write your Prisma Client queries here

  const createBook = await prisma.books.create({
    data: {
      name: 'book1',
      author_id: '1',
    },
  });

  console.log('createBook:',createBook);

  const books = await prisma.books.findMany({
    where: {
      author_id: '1',
    },
    select: {
      name: true,
      author_id: true,
      id: true,
    },
  });

  console.log('books:',books);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Here's the response

```js
createBook: {
  id: '04a86b46-0348-4aa3-99d4-9a28365c020c',
  name: 'book1',
  author_id: '1'
}

books: [
  {
    name: 'book1',
    author_id: '1',
    id: '04a86b46-0348-4aa3-99d4-9a28365c020c'
  }
]
```